# < Erro ao consumir api utilizando o REST Debugger >

Tags: delphi

Preciso consumir uma api para integrar com um sistema desenvolvido em Delphi, é necessário passar uma informação no header da requisição (chave/valor).

Dados da api:

- Url: https://diskfonepabxapi.azurewebsites.net/api/diskfonepabx
- Header (chave/valor): diskfonepabx-api-key/1f7a7aea-32d5-4b19-b9e2-1869d9d0d82e

Antes de implementar a requisição no Delphi testei via Postman e deu certo, conforme imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém, ao testar pelo REST Debugger do Delphi não está dando certo, tentei de várias maneiras, o que estou fazendo de errado?
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Poderiam me ajudar?

Comment: Na imagem do postman que postou existem headers hidden, poderia adicionar esses outros headers no `restdebugger.` e verificar se funciona. Na imagem da pra ver que existem 7 hidden headers. Mas eu creio que está faltando o header: `Content-Type: application/json`

Comment: @Danizavtz gostaria de agradecer, segui seu conselho e coloquei os headers hidden que estavam no Postman no REST Debugger e deu certo. 

Sou novo no Stack Overflow, como faço para classificar esse dúvida como atendida e associar ao seu nome? 

Mais uma vez obrigado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tendo em vista que foi possível fazer o request com sucesso via postman.
Para tentar resolver este problema específico, uma forma é clicar no botão `headers hidden` na interface do postman. Verificar quais os headers que o postman incluiu e adicionar ao rest debugger os mesmos headers.

Para isso:

- clicar no botão `headers hidden`.
- copiar os headers do postman e colar os headers no rest debugger.

Ao final você deve conseguir fazer o request no `restdebugger` caso os headers obrigatórios estejam presentes.